# two jquery dropdown work on create page, but not on edit page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, dropdown

I have 2nd dropdown that populates based on 1st dropdown, it works on creating a page but not on the edit page.

```
<!--This is my select dropdown-->
    <form>
        <select name="dep">
            <option>Department</option>
            <option>Sales</option>
            <option>Support</option>
        </select>
        <select name="cname">
            <option>Contact name</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $department = $("select[name='dep']");
    $cname = $("select[name='cname']");

    $department.change(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == "Sales") {
    $("select[name='cname'] option").remove();
    $("<option>John Smith</option>").appendTo($cname);
    $("<option>Marry Jones</option>").appendTo($cname);
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "Support") 
    {
    $("select[name='cname'] option").remove();
    $("<option>Jessy McBeth</option>").appendTo($cname);
    $("<option>Bob Smith</option>").appendTo($cname);
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "Department") 
    {
    $("select[name='cname'] option").remove();
    $("<option>Contact name</option>").appendTo($cname);
    }

    });
    });
    </script>
```

How do I make this work on my edit page?

The final result from that URL is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/c510xdrj/

Comment: where is that page ? what exactly not working ? please elaborate

Comment: the dropdown populate script doesn't work on edit page....

Comment: please elaborate more and show relevant code because your jsfiddle provided is working fine .